# Using the 'class' term in php without meaning the actual keyword

Tags: php, keyword

I am parsing a response from a webservice. 
in the parser section, i have something like this:

```
foreach ($resXml->readCalls->classify->classification ->class as $d) {
 ... do some processing
}
```

the problem is, the 'class' term which is a sub node in my xml response, is mistaken for the 'class' keyword in php, which raises a compile error.

how can i use terms which are incidentally a keyword in php?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you just do a simple `str_replace()` on the data beforehand, or is it likely to contain actual instances of the `class` keyword?

Comment: Uhm, you are sure that's the error? Afaik PHP switches to `ST_LOOKING_FOR_PROPERTY` after it encounters a `T_OBJECT_OPERATOR`. And in `ST_LOOKING_FOR_PROPERTY` any `{LABEL}` is considered a `T_STRING`. Thus you shouldn't get a `T_CLASS` there, theoretically. Could you provide the error message?

Comment: What @nikic is trying to say: `$resXml->readCalls->classify->classification->class` should not raise an error (and in fact, it doesnt): http://codepad.org/cteWoafH. Can you show some more of your code and/or tell us the name of the parser you are using?

Comment: what PHP version are you using ?

Comment: You need to tell us the exact error or we won't be able to help you. PHP doesn't give compile errors per se, unless you're compiling your PHP to binary/machine code.

Comment: @BoltClock: Compile errors don't have anything to do with compilation ;) PHP throws compile errors both while lexing and parsing. Just a not so well chosen term ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a [reserved word](http://php.net/manual/fa/reserved.php).  So you have to use it as a string:

```
foreach ($resXml->readCalls->classify->classification->{'class'} as $d) { 
    ... do some processing 
}
```

Or

```
$field = 'class';

foreach ($resXml->readCalls->classify->classification->$field as $d) { 
    ... do some processing 
}
```

Comment: @nikic: While I understand that it shouldn't raise the error, at the same time, it may fix it (as in for some reason the parser isn't switched into the `->` mode.  It's worth a try especially since the OP said he is getting the parse error...